# How to check the collection has data or not in magento2

Tags: magento2, collection

I have a method in block which i want to check is there any data available for a logged in customer in a custom history table.

```
public function checkHistryAvailable(){
    if($this->session->isLoggedIn()) {

        $customer_id = $this->session->getCustomer()->getId();
        $Rewardspointshistry = $this->rewardpointshistryFactory->create();

        $collection = $Rewardspointshistry->getCollection();

        $collection->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customer_id);
        if(is_null($collection)){ return 2; }else{ return 8; }
    }
}
```

I used **`is_null`** to check but it return the same result for two types.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check using `$collection->getSize()` method of collection.

```
if($collection->getSize() < 1){ return 2; }else{ return 8; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check using

```
count($collection->getData())
```

method of collection.

```
if(count($collection->getData()))
{
   return true; 
} else { 
   return false; 
}
```